# Flutter send variable to the other class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the below class like.dart that need to send some data to home.dart, the start page is the home dart and after click on button on post navigate to other page like.dart with parameters,  after user click on like I want to update the view on home.dart to show that user liked this post

```
      class imageModal extends StatefulWidget {
  //imageModal({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  final title;
  final comments;
  final links;
  final urlImages;
  final userid;
  final postid;
  final userlikes;
  int totallikes;
  final like;

  imageModal(this.title,this.comments,this.links,
  this.urlImages,this.postid,this.userid,this.userlikes,this.totallikes,this.like);
  @override
  imageModalState createState() => imageModalState();

  }
  ...
  new IconButton(
  icon: new Icon(Icons.favorite_border, color: Colors.black) ,
    onPressed: (){

    _like(widget.postid,state);
   }
   ),

   ...

  _like(postid,StateSetter updateState) async {  
  SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var userid = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('userid'));
  var user = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('user'));
  var data = {
  'userid' : userid,
  'postid': postid,
   };
  var res = await Network().like(data, 'post/like/');
  var body = json.decode(res.body);
  print(body['data']['users']);
    updateState(()  {
      widget.like.add(body['data']);
      //print( posts[i]['like']);
      widget.userlikes.add(body['data']);
      var totallikes = widget.totallikes;
      var finallikes = totallikes+1;
      widget.totallikes = finallikes;


    });



    }
```

I want to send to the home.dart the below values new values

```
 widget.like
widget.userlikes
widget.totallikes
```

and when I send them to setstate them so can update the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return from the other screen to home with the updated values, you can use `Navigator.pop(context, result);`

**In FirstScreen**

```
  _navigateToAnotherScreen(BuildContext context) async {
    final result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
    );

   // print(result);

  }
```

**In SecondScreen**

```
Navigator.pop(context, [value1, value2, value3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use state management technique like Provider

https://pub.dev/packages/provider